# Fetch data from mysql table using where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have categories in table I want to select data where category is Sales I am using following query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog_Master where category=@"Sales"");
```

Comment: It is good, if you are using PDO or MySQLi

Comment: `mysql_*` functions is from PHP5.5 DEPRECATED - use PDO [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?PHP
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog_Master WHERE category='Sales'");
?>
**EDIT**

**PHP 5.5 way**

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "db_user", "db_password", "db_name");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM catalog_Master WHERE category='Sales'");
```

Comment: Please add explanation. An Answer wothout explanation is barely an answer. Also: mysql_* is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.

Comment: how is this different from my answer? `:D`

Comment: I have update explanation please check it.

Comment: I still don't see explanation... However, at least the mysqli_is there.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with single quotes because it is a string.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog_Master where category='Sales'");
```

based on your comment, if you want the value from a variable,

```
$category="Sales";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog_Master where category='$category'");
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: if i want to give this in var then how can give this like $category="Sales" like this or not

Comment: how to call this page using url lie mypage.com/catalog.php?category=? like this if i want to post category

Comment: `$category=$_GET["category"]` will return "sales" if your url is "http:// mypage.com/catalog.php?category=sales"

Comment: +1 for mentioning PDO, SQL injection. Nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

be careful with the double quotes, also if it's an exact match:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog_Master where category='Sales'");
```

This should work